# Line formation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, line

I am a new user of not only Matlab but stackoverflow. I am looking for an information as I just started using Matlab. I went through basic commands of matlab but I am not getting an idea of how to work with below problem statement.

I want to create the below graph

[image]

There are two lines and the angle between them is variable from zero degree till 30 degree and the length of lines can be taken anything.

It will be helpful if anyone lets me know how to create the above figure in matlab.

Thanks

Comment: In your picture the angle between the two line seems ranging up to 120° (30° seems the angle of the first line with resepct to the X axis. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Considering the dotted angle as zero degree, I want to plot the angle with respect to horizontal line

You are right as 30° is the angle of the first line with resepct to the X axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to plot a line, you just need to define the `(x,y)` coordinates of the *starting* and *ending* point of the line itself

For a given angle `theta` and a given starting point, you can define coordinates of the line using `sin` and `cos` functions (`sind` and `cosd` if `theta` is in `deg`):

```
x_start=1;
y_start=3;
x_coord=[x_start x_start+r*cosd(theta)]
y_coord=[y_start y_start+r*sind(theta(i))]
```

In your case, you can use a `for` loop to generate all the lines with `theta` ranging from `0` to `30°`.

This is a possible implementation: at each iteration of the `for` loop, a line is plotted and displayed for `1 sec` than it is deleted.

```
% Define the length of the line
r=3;
% Define the starting point coordinates
x_start=1;
y_start=3;
% Define the set of angles (in radiants)
theta=[0:30];
% Open a Figure
figure
% Add the axes
axes
daspect([1 1 1])
hold on
% Plot the reference line
x_ref=[x_start r+x_start]
y_ref=[y_start y_start]
xlim([0 r+x_start])
ylim([0 r+y_start])
plot(x_ref,y_ref,'--b','linewidth',2)
grid minor
% Plot the line
for i=1:length(theta)
   % Plot the line
   pl_h=plot([x_start x_start+r*cosd(theta(i))], ...
      [y_start y_start+r*sind(theta(i))],'r','linewidth',2)
   xlim([0 r+x_start])
   ylim([0 r+y_start])
   % Add a string displaying the value of the current angle
   tx_h=text(1,2,['Angle= ' num2str(theta(i)) ' [Deg]'])
   pause(1)
   delete([tx_h pl_h])
end
```

[image]

Hope this helps,

Qapla'